# Error due to variable scope in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I have the following code

```
function scraping_digg() {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html('http://digg.com/');

    // get news block
    foreach($html->find('div.news-summary') as $article) {
        // get title
        $item['title'] = trim($article->find('h3', 0)->plaintext);
        // get details
        $item['details'] = trim($article->find('p', 0)->plaintext);
        // get intro
        $item['diggs'] = trim($article->find('li a strong', 0)->plaintext);

        $ret[] = $item;
    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}
```

When I run it I get the following error.

```
Undefined variable: ret in /opt/lampp/htdocs/web_scrapper/example/scraping/example_scraping_digg.php on line
```

I can't find the fix for the scope of $ret. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that `$html->find('div.news-summary')` does not return empty array?

Comment: Doesn't Digg have an API? Is it because $html->find('div.news-summary') doesn't produce any results?

Comment: Yes. It div.news-summary was not working. I changed it to what is is now. Then it works. And $ret = array() also helped me get rid of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beggining of `scraping_digg` function declare variable:

```
$ret = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

The line number would be the most important information!

```
 $ret[] = $item;
```

This line will likely trigger the notice, at the start of the function add something like

```
$ret=array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because `$ret` is undefined...

Try declaring `$ret` before your loop

```
function scraping_digg() {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html('http://digg.com/');
    $ret = array();

    // get news block
    foreach($html->find('div.news-summary') as $article) {
        // get title
        $item['title'] = trim($article->find('h3', 0)->plaintext);
        // get details
        $item['details'] = trim($article->find('p', 0)->plaintext);
        // get intro
        $item['diggs'] = trim($article->find('li a strong', 0)->plaintext);

        $ret[] = $item;
    }

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't initialize both `$ret` and `$item` within the function scope.

```
function scraping_digg() {
        // create HTML DOM
        $html = file_get_html('http://digg.com/');
        $ret = array();
        // get news block
        foreach($html->find('div.news-summary') as $article) {
            $item = array();
            // get title
            $item['title'] = trim($article->find('h3', 0)->plaintext);
            // get details
            $item['details'] = trim($article->find('p', 0)->plaintext);
            // get intro
            $item['diggs'] = trim($article->find('li a strong', 0)->plaintext);

            $ret[] = $item;
        }

        // clean up memory
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);

        return $ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't even find any `div` with the class of `news-summary` on digg's homepage. That `foreach` loop probably never get executed because PHP couldn't find any of the `div` you're looking for. Thus, `$ret` is never declared.

However you could add `$ret = array();` at the top of the function as hsz mentioned in his answer to make the error message go away.

Comment: Yes. news-summary is not present. I used the sample from library that's why I couldn't get it. But $ret = array() is really helpful.